# how can i insert xml response to class object in c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, class, xml-serialization

I am working on a project have a code which is posting data to payment integration url and the response I am getting is in xml string format, I want to insert that response string in class object so that I can use it to display in view to user

I am entering the values in my code as for sample as I cannot share original info.

I am getting the response string in following format:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n
<REFUND>
    <MERCHANTID>123</MERCHANTID>
    <TRANSACTIONID>100045448545</TXNID>
    <AMOUNT>100.00</AMOUNT>
    <STATUSCODE>M5</STATUSCODE>
    <STATUSMESSAGE>Invalid transaction date</STATUSMESSAGE>
    <REFUNDID>NA</REFUNDID>
</REFUND>
```

I'm using this code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("merchantid", "123"));
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pwd", "hjcjsjjcj="));
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("transactionid", "1000046558989"));
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refundamt", "100.00"));
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("transactiondate", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refundreferance", "25631"));

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("payment url", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(REFUND), new XmlRootAttribute("REFUND"));
    var stringReader = new StringReader(responseString);
    var reader = xmlSer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    return RedirectToAction("View", reader);
}
```

Here is the class which I used where I want to insert the response:

```
[Serializable()]
public class REFUNDVW
{
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("MERCHANTID")]
        public string MERCHANTID { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("TRANSACTIONID")]
        public string TXNID { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("AMOUNT")]
        public string AMOUNT { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("STATUSCODE")]
        public string STATUSCODE { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("STATUSMESSEGE")]
        public string STATUSMESSEGE { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("REFUNDID")]
        public string REFUNDID{ get; set; }
}

[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class REFUND
{
        [XmlArray("REFUND")]
        public List<REFUNDVW> Refunds { get; set; }

        public REFUND()
        {
            Refunds = new List<REFUNDVW>();
        }
}
```

I want to store the XML response string in the instance of the class which I have created and pass it to a Razor view to display it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things wrong

Here is updated Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REFUND>
  <MERCHANTID>123</MERCHANTID>
  <TRANSACTIONID>100045448545</TRANSACTIONID>
  <AMOUNT>100.00</AMOUNT>
  <STATUSCODE>M5</STATUSCODE>
  <STATUSMESSAGE>Invalid transaction date</STATUSMESSAGE>
  <REFUNDID>NA</REFUNDID>
</REFUND>
```

I fixed the following :

1. Removed the \n at end of first line
2. The open and close tags did not match on the 4th line.
3. The classes show and Array In Refund but the Xml has all the elements in the class Refund
4. You have following in the Class REFUND : [XmlArray("REFUND")] which indicates the class Refund has a child class Refund
5. Here is the code I used which does not give exceptions but only returns the root class REFUND due to the classes and the XML not matching

   ```
           string responseString = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
           XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(REFUND));

           StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(responseString);
           REFUND  reader = (REFUND)xmlSer.Deserialize(stringReader);
   ```

Comment: but i am getting that xml string as a response so this line  string responseString = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME); is valid in that context  also should i use only one class with name REFUND and assign the field for the xml elements

Comment: Then delete the class REFUNDVW and put all the properties into REFUND.

Comment: so this only class would be REFUND and should i have to assign this  [XmlRoot("REFUND")] for the class

Comment: what about this line string responseString = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

Comment: I read file from for testing.  So you just need to use your responseString instead of my responseString.  Yes you can use XmlRoot["REFUND"].